# Key binding to toggle between two languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a Django project. Therefore, I am working with Django templates.

When editing templates, I keep on switching between languages in order to benefit from HTML and Django templates.

Typically, I would set VSCode language to HTML in order to create the HTML content. Then I would switch to Django-template in order to add the Django specific stuff.

Unfortunately, the process of switching is somehow slow:

- command palette
- change language mode (which can be shorter by cmd+k m)
- HTML

and so on...

Is there a way to create a key binding that would toggle between 2 languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an extension to use a VSC API function in a keybinding: [Change Language Mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.change-language-mode)

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k d",
    "command": "changeLanguageMode.change",
    "args": "html",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'django-html'"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+k d",
    "command": "changeLanguageMode.change",
    "args": "django-html",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'html'"
}
```